# how to convert a while loop to recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

I have this method in Java that returns the correct amount of medicine

```
public static double medicinasobrantew(int cantidaddedias, double cantidadmedicina){
    double medicinasobrante;
    while(cantidaddedias > 1){
        cantidadmedicina = cantidadmedicina - (cantidadmedicina * 0.2);
        cantidaddedias--;
    }
    medicinasobrante = cantidadmedicina;
    return medicinasobrante;
}
```

I need to convert it to a recursive method that returns the same value to me, I have this method, but when printing the value it returns 1. I don't know what I'm failing at.

```
public static double medicinasobranterecursivo(int cantidaddedias, double cantidadmedicina) {
    int cantidaddediasprint = cantidaddedias;
    if (cantidaddedias == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("La cantidad de medicina en su cuerpo es:" + cantidadmedicina);

        return   medicinasobranterecursivo(cantidaddedias - 1,   cantidadmedicina-(cantidadmedicina*0.2) );
    }
}
```

thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hi @CindyMendoza - you should try each scenario with both method - and see you get the value you expect ... And the print shouldn't be in the recursive method (which is why are getting odd values)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
public static double medicinasobrantew(int cantidaddedias, double cantidadmedicina){
    if(cantidaddedias<=1)
        {
            return cantidadmedicina;
        }
    else
        {
            cantidadmedicina = cantidadmedicina - (cantidadmedicina * 0.2);
            return medicinasobrantew(cantidaddedias-1, cantidadmedicina);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Haridas, this answer returns the value I need

Answer (score 0):

The while loop doesn't do anything when `cantidaddedias <= 1`. When the while loop doesn't do anything, `cantidadmedicina` is returned. Therefore, the base case for the recursive function should be:

```
if (cantidaddedias <= 1) {
  return cantidadmedicina;
}
```

The recursive case seems to be correct, but note that `cantidadmedicina-(cantidadmedicina*0.2)` can be simplified to `cantidadmedicina * 0.8`